# Why the threads stop when the other start to execute?

Tags: java, multithreading, pool

I'm new to Java concurrent API and I've searched but didn't find an answer to my question.

Well, I have a code that look for every file inside directories and their subdirectories and another that copy every found file that match a specified pattern.

I separate this codes in one *Runnable* implementation called **DirSearch** and one *Callable* implementation called **FileSearch** and submit them using an *ExecutorService*.

That's the code:

```
private boolean execute() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsNumber);
    BlockingQueue<File> dirQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    BlockingQueue<File> fileQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10000);

    boolean isFinished = false;

    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < dirThreads; i++) {
            executor.submit(new DirSearch(dirQueue, fileQueue, count, dirThreads);
        }

        count.incrementAndGet();
        dirQueue.add(baseDir);

        Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(new FileSearch(filequeue, outputDirectory, filename));

        isFinished = future.get();
    } catch(ExecutionException | InterruptedException | RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

    return isFinished;
}

...

private void copyFile(File in, File out) {
    Path inPath = Paths.get(in.getAbsolutePath());
    Path outPath = Paths.get(out.getAbsolutePath(), in.getName());

    try {
        main.updateCurrentLabel(outPath.toString());

        switch(mode) {
            case "1":
                Files.copy(inPath, outPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                break;
            case "2":
                Files.move(inPath, outPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        main.updateCopiedLabel(String.valueOf(countCpFiles.incrementAndGet()));
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

...

private class DirSearch implements Runnable {

    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            File dir = dirQueue.take();

            while(dir != new File("")) {
                File[] elements = dir.listFiles();

                if(elements != null) {
                    for(File element : elements) {
                        if(element.isDirectory()) {
                            count.incrementAndGet();
                            dirQueue.put(element);
                        } else {
                            fileQueue.put(element);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(count.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                    end();
                }

                dir = dirQueue.take();
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ...

}

...

private class FileSearch implements Callable<Boolean> {

    ...

    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        boolean isFinished = false;

        try {
            File file = fileQueue.take();

            while(file != new File("")) {
                incrementAnalyzed();
                String foundFile = file.getName().toLowerCase();

                if(foundFile.matches(filename.replace("?", ".?").replace("*", ".*?"))) {
                    copyFile(file, outputDirectory);
                }

                file = fileQueue.take();
            }

            isFinished = true;
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return isFinished;
    }
}
```

The problem is: when the **FileSearch** start to copy files, the other threads (**DirSearch**) stop and don't look for any new file until the copy is completed. Why this is happening? Am I doing anything wrong or this is not the correct approach?

Comment: What are the values of `dirThreads` and `threadsNumber`?

Comment: Note that `dir != ""` won't compile.

Comment: @AndyTurner The _threadsNumber_ is an input from the user and _dirThreads_ is threadsNumber - 1. I wrote the whole by hand, cause it's not in the same computer, it's my mistake the dir != "". Check the editted question.

Answer (score -1):

Two possible answers which came to my mind and which i cant guarantee they apply to your specific situation:
1. Java VM gets only one core from your CPU which means it can only run one thread at a time.
2. your threads both use the same variable which means only one is allowed to really manipulate it at a time. For this specific problem look up java keyword "synchronized".
I guess the root of the problem tends to be #1